# Quotes ignore brackets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to place a sign to copy the use of Essentials' [Buy] Command, using this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ wall_sign 5 replace {id:Sign,Text1:"[Buy]"}
```

But that command gives me this when it is executed

[image]

It seems as if even though the brackets are in Quotes, the command is seeing them as an exectuable string. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a work-around. Apparently /blockdata Doesn't ignore brackets in quotes. So instead of the /setblock I used

```
/blockdata ~ ~-1 ~ { Text1: "{ text:\"[Buy]\", color:dark_blue,clickEvent: { action:run_command, value:\"/setblock ~-2 ~ ~ redstone_block\" } }",Text2:"All Purchases",Text3:"Are Non-", Text4:"Refundable!"}
```

To make the sign.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why square brackets don't work without the `\` slashes. (Clue: *It's something to do with json arrays*)

Comment: No need to use blockdata. The real change that made it work was to switch from the simple `Text1:"[Buy]"` to a full composite JSON: `Text1:"{text:\"[Buy]\"}"` (which you need anyway to make it do stuff).